# What does ampersand & do in a function name?

Tags: c++

I understand that having an ampersand before declaring a variable in a function is a call by reference, and it will modify variable i created in my `main` function.

```
int my_func(int &my_var){
    my_var += 9;
    return my_var;
}


int main(void){
    int some_var = 1;
    my_func(some_var); // value of some_var is now 10
    return 0;
```

However, what does an ampersand before a function name do? For example

```
int &my_func(int &my_var){
    my_var +=9;
    return my_var;
}
```

Comment: It returns an `int&`.

Answer (score 0):

The `&` has nothing to do with the function name here. The white spaces are misleading. Use a formatter, like clang format.

```
int& my_func(int& my_var)
```

the return type of `my_func` is a reference type of `int`